# Webclient upload file - internal server error 500

Tags: c#, curl

I have been trying to emulate the following cURL command through the following C# code:

```
curl.exe –v –u user:pwd –XPOST –T "file1.txt" –H "Content-Type:text/plain" "http://example.com/xx/xx/xx/insert"
```

```
string url = "http://example.com/xx/xx/xx/insert";
string fileName = @"file1.txt";

var client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");         
byte[] responseBinary = client.UploadFile(url, "POST", fileName);
string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBinary);
```

It gives me an "Internal server error 500". I think the server which I am trying to upload to is a PHP server. How should I proceed to debug?

Comment: You might need to go to the server and see the actual exception you are getting.  Is this a Console Application? Make sure you added file1.txt as a "CopyAlways" resource. If it's a website, the default folder windows looks for files is in the Windows dir. So you might need a Request.MapPath or similar.

Comment: @flaviotsf : I am trying to upload from a console application to the server. So you mean that apart from making file1.txt as "CopyAlways", I will also need to see the php server code to figure out what is happening ?

Comment: Yes, the file should be in the same directory of your application. Other than that, your code looks fine! Maybe you need to pass a domain on the NetworkCredential constructor? Does the CURL command works? If so, you can always call it using a system.diagnostics.process

Comment: @flaviotsf : Thanks. System.diagnostics.process solves the problem. Only one question I have is that, using System.diagnostics.process I may not have much control over the error... it is just what the cURL returns ?

Comment: Yeah.. now you are getting a 500, what doesn't help much either. I'm unsure how curl works but you might be able to check the exit code of the process. Usually 0 is success and 1 is error. Maybe you can have log4net email you in case of an exception or do a retry after i.e. 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Update :

I was debugging traffic of cURL and webclient (console application) through fiddler. It looks like that cURL sends only contents of file1.txt and keeps the header as "text/plain". The webclient adds Content-Disposition, filename, content-type to contents of file1.txt and makes headers as "multipart/form-data".

Is there anyway I can stop webclient's this behavior ?

Thanks,
Kanu

Comment: Update : Used webrequest [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)